# How to use Authenticator subclass in a Java EE application with JavaMail

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail, mail-server, james

In Java SE its easy to support the authentication part with such code :

```
Session session = session.getInstance(props,new MyAuthenticator());
```

But in Java EE the session instance is not created by the application, but its supplied by JNDI injection  by the application server in the application.

```
@Resource(name = "mail/JMsession")
private Session session
```

How to handle the authentication part here? 
What about the authenticationType argument in the @Resource annotation

```
@Resource(name = "mail/JMsession", authenticationType = AuthenticationType.APPLICATION)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java EE you can use the [@MailSessionDefinition](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/MailSessionDefinition.html) annotation (or its equivalent in XML) to define the mail [Session](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Session.html) that you later on inject.

Its `user` and `password` attributes are the declarative version of the programmatic [Authenticator](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Authenticator.html)'s [PasswordAuthentication](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/PasswordAuthentication.html).

`@MailSessionDefinition` is available on Java EE 7 servers, such as GlassFish 4 and also already in WildFly 8 (previously JBoss AS 8).

Comment: how can i use this annotation in my application, should i replace the session annotation with this annotation to support the authentication purpose ?

Comment: @primeFaceUser You should not replace anything. `@MailSessionDefinition` DEFINES the mail session, while `@Resource ... Session` is the point where you USE this mail session. It's defined once (put it on a random class) and potentially used at many locations.

Answer (score 1):

Normally in Java EE you should configure authentication in the same place as other properties for container-supplied sessions. For example for Glassfish this configuration can be found in the Admin UI / Resources / JavaMail Sessions. So, Authenticator is generally applicable only to SE-style:

```
Session session = session.getInstance(props,new MyAuthenticator());
```

Java EE configuration-based approach limits you to fixed number of preconfigured sessions. It, however, makes sense for most applications as they usually send mails via a fixed mail relay server.